# Can I play as Batarian, Elcor, Geth, Hanar, Rachni or Volus in ME3 multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Can I play as Batarian, Elcor, Geth, Hanar, Rachni or Volus in *Mass Effect 3's* multiplayer mode? So far only Asari, Human, Krogan, Quarian, Salarian & Turian have been announced.

Comment: Apparently questions about upcoming releases are off topic. [I just found out about this myself.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48534/who-is-the-virmire-survivor#comment70207_48534).

Comment: Until the game is out, no one can provide an expert answer. Flag it for reopening come March, and I'll undo this.

Comment: The demo is out and gives multiplayer options, does that count? Looks like the answer's going to be no, though...

Comment: Elcor and Hanar seem rather unlikely considering their physique, and Volus tend to prefer to hire others to do their killing for them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [**Mass Effect wiki**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer)

There are only 7 playable races

- [**Human**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Human)
- [**Drell**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Drell)
- [**Asari**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Asari)
- [**Krogan**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Krogan)
- [**Quarian**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Quarian)
- [**Salarian**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Salarian)
- [**Turian**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Turian)

As a side note, only humans can be every single class.  The wiki also has a [table](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Multiplayer#Class_and_Race) for class/race combinations.

---

**DLCs**:

As of the [**Resurgence DLC pack**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Resurgence_Pack)(free), the following races were added:

- [**Batarian**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Batarian)
- [**Geth**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Geth)

As of the [**Rebellion DLC Pack**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Rebellion_Pack)(free), the following races were added:

- [**Vorcha**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Vorcha)
- [**Quarian**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Quarian)
- [**Project Phoenix**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer/Character_Customization/Vanguard#Project_Phoenix_Vanguard) (Modified Human)

As of the [**Earth DLC Pack**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Earth)
(Free)

- [**N7**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer/Character_Customization/Adept#N7_Fury_Adept)(Modified Human)

As of the [**Retaliation DLC Pack**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Retaliation)(free)

- [**Volus**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer/Character_Customization/Adept#Volus_Adept)

Comment: Stupid DLC.  Now this answer needs updating.  <grumble grumble>

Comment: @MBraedley Done :p

Comment: @TylerShads: Just a ping to say you might like to update this answer. I've not played MP for a while so don't know what else there might be now but know there was Volus floating about last time I was playing at least...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. They might release dlc for that, not update.

Answer (score -3):

http://sticktwiddlers.com/2012/03/12/mass-effect-3-secret-multiplayer-characters-leaked/
You may find that interesting.

Comment: Please don't just post links as answers. Do summarize enough from what's behind the jump to make the answer still useful even when that link will inevitably rot.